# A PYomo "RuntimeError"

Tags: pyomo

I posted earlier under the heading "PYomo AttributeError Message" and got a help which seems to have fixed that issue. However, I am facing a new problem, "RuntimeError". Kindly see the attached screenshots for your reference.
[image]

[image]

I shall kindly be grateful for any assistance to help me fix this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a Pyomo Set declared where the values in the set depend on the values in another set or a parameter. This is a perfectly valid thing to do but it will cause problems if you try to iterate over the set before constructing the model (which is what happens when you call pprint). The easiest way to fix this is to move the pprint call to after model construction:

```
instance = model.create("Katrina_paper.dat")
instance.pprint()
```

Comment: Bethany, it worked! I am very grateful for your assistance. Thank you.